# Function to check for foreign key references when inserting new records

Tags: mysql

Given two tables:

```
-- Create table: city (FK)
CREATE TABLE city (
    city_id             INT                 PRIMARY KEY         AUTO_INCREMENT,
    city_name           VARCHAR(150)        NOT NULL            UNIQUE
);

-- Create table: organizations
CREATE TABLE organization (
    id              INT                     PRIMARY KEY         AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name            VARCHAR(150),
    city_fk         INT,

    -- foreign key constraint
    CONSTRAINT organization_fk_city
        FOREIGN KEY (city_fk)
        references city (city_id)
);
```

---

And given a CSV text file with the format below:

```
12332, Slack, Columbia
21242, Jackson, Columbia
23323, Thompson, Annapolis
```

---

I have to parse this CSV file into my table, but am wondering how I can check to see if a record already exists in the city table with the same name.

Is there a SQL function/query to check 'city' for matching foreign key entity?

I have this SQL 'function' I've created, but am not sure how to use it when inserting a record.

```
CREATE FUNCTION find_city(NAME VARCHAR) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    # initilize variables
    DECLARE ID_FOUND INT DEFAULT 0;

    -- Declare variable to hold results
    ID_FOUND = SELECT city_id FROM city WHERE city_name = NAME;

    -- If records are returned?
    CASE 
      -- Return the foreign key ID found 
      WHEN ID_FOUND >= 1 THEN RETURN ID_FOUND
      -- Insert new record into table
      ELSE INSERT INTO `donorsearch`.`city` (`city_name`) VALUES (NAME);
    END
END//
```

Comment: inserting how? you're doing a `load data infile`? or parsing the csv externally and issuing `insert` queries?

Comment: I was planning on parsing externally in PHP - it is a fairly large file (70MB), but just was wondering for reference using a standard `insert` query for test data

Comment: simplest method: run the insert query, then check the query error code for success or FK violation. `load infile` is basically useless for per-line errors, because you only get an error for the load as a whole. all lines import successfully, or the entire load is considered a failure.

Comment: Bring it into a worktable, and do comparisons from there via sql. Having PHP drive this thing will bring performance to its knees. If you need help with this, let us know.

Answer (score 1):

If you're importing programmatically (as you indicate you are doing with php), and performing a lot of inserts (as a 70MB csv with short lines would suggest), your best option is:

- cache the city table's name and id values into a local keyed set (keyed on the value expected from the csv)
- reference that to find id values as you go

  - If a value is not found, perform the appropriate INSERT into the city table and retrieve the new row's id for your local cache and continue.

---

*You could make a sql function to take the name, insert it if missing, and return the id; as your original idea seemed to be heading; but that means that check would be repeated for every single row you insert in this manner.*